# How to use google static map api for showing regions of the world

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I want to use Google Maps Image APIs for showing highlighted regions from the world. regions could be region or combination of country and regions. So I will have regions array and i want map images to generated pointing out passed regions. How to do that using Google maps image API